# Custom Module for Friquently asked question in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3

develop module for creating FAQ's of visitor's of our website using admin grid(Crud Operation) and on FAQ page those FAQ's can be viewed and all answer's also viewed on that page.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem. It doesn't look like you got one... go for it! good luck :)

Comment: Check the answer of Devidas, this is perfect for you

Comment: no it;snot perfect for me

Answer (score 2):

go through this module to develop custom faq module

https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-faqs-extensions